# How complicated must a real with an "easy total computability problem" be to compute?

Tags: logic, computability

For (noncomputable) $A\subseteq\omega$ let $\tilde{A}=\{e: \varphi_e^A\mbox{ is total and }\exists c(\varphi_e^A\simeq\varphi_c)\}$. A priori $\tilde{A}$ is $\Sigma^0_3(A)$ ("$\varphi_e^A$ is total and there is some $c$ such that on all inputs we eventually see agreement between $\varphi_c$ and $\varphi_e^A$"). However, this bound isn't sharp in general: [if $A$ is sufficiently Cohen generic then $\tilde{A}$ is $\Pi^0_2(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4179424/28111) *(of course we can't do better than this: $\tilde{A}$ is always $\Pi^0_2(A)$-hard)*.

However, a fair amount of genericity (at a glance, $2$-genericity) is needed for that argument. This raises the question of how hard it must be to compute a real nontrivially satisfying "$\tilde{A}$ is not $\Sigma^0_3(A)$-complete." Specifically:

> Does every nonrecursive $\Delta^0_2$ set $A$ satisfy "$\tilde{A}$ is $\Sigma^0_3$-complete"?

Genericity-based arguments almost certainly won't be useful here, since there aren't even any $\Delta^0_2$ *weak* $2$-generics.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but surely this would do better at mathoverflow?

Comment: @TonyK I'm not sure - I'm not certain that it's actually that hard, I could easily be missing a very simple trick (and there are plenty of very hard questions here on MSE!). I try to reserve MO for when I'm reasonably certain that a question is genuinely difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [answered by Ted Slaman](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396519/is-there-a-delta0-2-real-with-easy-total-computability-problem) at mathoverflow - contra my guess, genericity arguments *do* suffice. Specifically, any $1$-generic $\Delta^0_2$ set $A$ satisfies "$\tilde{A}$ is a Boolean combination of $\Sigma^0_2(A)$ sets (so a fortiori isn't $\Sigma^0_3(A)$-complete)." See his answer for details.

*(I've made this answer CW to avoid reputation gain from his work, but I did want to move this off the unanswered queue.)*